# Need for/while/do while loops to repeat asterisks

Tags: javascript, html

I have this problem, to repeat 30 asterisks for 3 lines. I made this example code but it repeats 30 numbers (1..30) from 1 number for first line, up to 30 numbers for the last line. So, I'd need the code to repeat 30 asterisks, for 3 lines each but not quite like within this code.

*Sorry for bad elaboration.*

```
var text = "";
var max = 30;

for(i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        text += (j+1)+" ";
    }
    text += "<br />";
}
```

Comment: You should go for sth like this `text += "*";`

Comment: What do you mean by asterisks?

Comment: @Ahmad I mean the asterisk symbol (*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeat the loop three times, like this:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) { // this is the line loop
    for ( var j = 0; j < 30; j++ ) { //this is the asterix loop
        document.write('*');
    }
    document.write('<br>');
}
```

Here's a [simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dwa98beb/)

Comment: Thank you @giorgio! This was the exact solution I was looking for!

Comment: Don't forget to `var` your variables: `var i` and `var j`.

Answer (score 2):

A more re-usable solution will be to make a generic `repeatString` function that simply makes multiple copies of any string.

```
function repeatString(s, times) {
    for (var i = 0, r = ''; i < times; i++) {
        r += s;
    }
    return r;
}
var line = repeatString('*', 30) + '<br />',
    content = repeatString(line, 3);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/611y2vmz/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ES2015 (ES6) syntax you can leverage [repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) function and [string templating](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings?hl=en). Using those features your code will look like this

```
let text = (`${'*'.repeat(30)}<br/>`).repeat(3);
```

[Here is an example of ES2015 (ES6) code](https://jsfiddle.net/kkjjfp6j/)

if you are using ES5 then you can do this way:

```
String.prototype.repeat = function(count) {
    return count < 1 ? '' : new Array(count + 1).join(this);
};

var text = ('*'.repeat(30) + '<br/>').repeat(3);
```

[Here is an example of ES5 code](https://jsfiddle.net/4bgxfpao/)

Answer (score 0):

You need your outer loop to iterate 3 times, and your inner loop to iterate 30 times. Each iteration of your inner loop should add an asterisk (instead of adding `j+1` like you are doing now). This will produce 3 rows of 30 asterisks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var TEXT = "*";
var LINE_SEPARATOR = "<br/>";

var TEXT_COUNT = 30;
var LINE_COUNT = 3;

var output = "";

for (line = 1; line <= LINE_COUNT; ++line) {
    for (text = 1; text <= TEXT_COUNT; ++text) {
        output += TEXT;
    }
    output += LINE_SEPARATOR;
}

document.write(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use recursion:

```
function stars(num) {
  return num > 0 ? stars(num - 1) + '*' : '';
}

var content = stars(30) + '<br/>' + stars(30) + '<br/>' + stars(30);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k3wLs95n/1/)

Comment: Why?! When there is a simple way without recursion.

Comment: Recursive operations are used when there is no way instead. Because they are so much heavier than loops.

Comment: I tried that and iteration was faster. And even without that test, that's so clear.